# Xcode - storyboard - Navigation controller

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4.2, storyboard, navigationcontroller

I have attached a navigation controller to my storyboard. Initially, I had the nafigation bar title available and I changed the title from "Root Controller" to something else. Today, I found that the navigation bar disappeared and I could not change the title at the navigation bar. Although, the view acts without any problem when I simulate it and I can see in the simulator the current title but not anymore in my xcode.

Any idea? or how to change the title programmatically?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Setting the Navigation controller title programatically from your rootViewController…

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"Your Title";
```

From your description of the issue I can't explain why it's missing in storyboard.